# How to fix exception 404 in Django views?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm following this tutorial:https://www.w3schools.com/django/django_views.php

After copying all the code to create the members and admin views I get this error:
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in myworld.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

1. members/
2. admin/

The empty path didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project `urls.py` you set the path to the members app to use `127.0.0.1:8000/members`

In order to navigate to `127.0.0.1:8000/members` using the default route, you need to change the path to look like this :

```
path('', include('members.urls')),
```

Comment: Thank you. My code was path('members', include('members.urls')), That's why it wasn't working. Kinda ironic, cause I thought the problem was the empty path. But I'm still getting 404 for the main page.